# Error: Bundler "EXE Installer" (exe) failed to produce a bundle

Tags: java, maven, javafx, ant

I am currently trying to deploy a Javafx Project im working on. 
The last bundle deployed just fine and without a single error.

Since the last deployment I added the log4j library to my project and changed a few lines of code, but nothing to special I haven't used in my project before.

Now I am getting an error when trying to deploy the newest version of my project.

Im receiving the following error:

> [fx:deploy] java.io.IOException: Exec failed with code 2 command
>   [[C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe,
>   /oC:\Users\Technik\Desktop\preisvergleich\PriceChecker\build\deploy\bundles,
>   C:\Users\Technik\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler5453073401556757755\images\win-exe.image\Preischecker.iss]
>   in
>   C:\Users\Technik\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler5453073401556757755\images\win-exe.image
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:165) [fx:deploy]
>     at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:138)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:132) [fx:deploy]
>     at
>   com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WinExeBundler.buildEXE(WinExeBundler.java:697)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WinExeBundler.bundle(WinExeBundler.java:366)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WinExeBundler.execute(WinExeBundler.java:173)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:352)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:319)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask.execute(DeployFXTask.java:286)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>   [fx:deploy]   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) [fx:deploy]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   [fx:deploy]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>   [fx:deploy]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
>   [fx:deploy]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:448)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:469) [fx:deploy]
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1370)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:460)
>   [fx:deploy]   at
>   org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:142)
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\Users\Technik\Desktop\preisvergleich\PriceChecker\build\build.xml:149:
>   Error: Bundler "EXE Installer" (exe) failed to produce a bundle.
>
> Total time: 3 seconds

Btw I am using eclipse, javafx 10, maven, inno setup 5 and try to deploy my project via ant.

I hope someone can give me a hint how to fix the problem. If any code is required to find the problem I can post it.

As far as I can see im getting an ioexception in the first line of the error message. But my program is working completely fine and I'm not getting any io exceptions.

Comment: why are you trying to build an EXE?

Comment: Im trying to deploy it as an exe for easy installation on other machines. it worked just fine before

Comment: a build to an exe has not much to do with a deployment. Either way, I don't see anything immediately in that stacktrace pointing to a cause

Comment: Okay. Thanks anyway.